# Convert Entity result to a different model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I don't really know how to describe this very well...

I want to use a model that is inherited from my entity `DbSet` without doing the mapping every time?

Entity database set

```
public DbSet<MyDataTable> MyDataTable { get; set; }
```

The model

```
public class MyDataTable 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string dataField1 { get; set; }      
}
```

The model I'd like to use in my controller instead of `MyDataTable`:

```
public class MyData : MyDataTable 
{
    public string dataField2 { get; set; }

    public bool dataCalc() 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My controller code:

```
public class MyController 
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public MyController(private readonly DbContext _context;)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<<List<MyData>>>> GetData
    {
        // This works if it is List<MyDataTable>
        // Easy way to get it in List<MyData>  ?
        // Or do I get List<MyDataTable> then map MyDataTable to MyData
        List<MyData> dataList = await _context.MyDataTable
                                              .Select(s => s).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I would usually just map `MyDataTable` to `MyData` manually, or use AutoMapper.

Is there a more advanced way to do this?

Cheers!

Further claification:

Sorry if this seems like a silly question! I have noticed that I am fetching data from the database in one model MyDataTable then mapping it to MyData in every call. There's a lot of similar code around, and it doesn't confirm to DRY "Don't Repeat Yourself".

Is there a different way to structure this?

Comment: What issue you are having with? The most common approach to use an auto mapper, in addition to this, you also can manually bind your domain model to your custom model as well.

Comment: Get `MyDataTable` into memory, then do mapping; and let the model or the entity have convert function, instead of do the mapping everywhere. You can use auto mapper in such functions, and still keep the convertion in one place - callers just need to use that function you provided to get the wanted class, instead of figuring out how to map.

Comment: Thanks Xiang, I knew there was something I was missing! Can you explain the "convert function" in more detail? I'd usually just do mapping everywhere.

Comment: [Implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really know how to describe this very well...
>
> I want to use a model that is inherited from my entity DbSet without
> doing the mapping every time?
>
> I would usually just map MyDataTable to MyData manually, or use
> AutoMapper.
>
> Is there a more advanced way to do this?

Well based on your scenario and description, before proceeding to advanced knowledge, I think you ought to take a look at the basics first, in order to know what developers commonly do in practice.

You should have different classes to model your domain than your DB model or entity Model. The most important point is to keep in mind,  if you attempt to map your domain objects directly, on every occasion, you have to change them to match what you need your data structure to be, and possibly expose things you don't want to expose.

Another important point is that, it's a [violation of the Single Responsibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp) principle of [SOLID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp); your class has two reasons to change if you make it your domain object and map it directly.

However, depending on business needs and requirements we need to decide how to proceed but it's always good to keep the data model complete separate from the domain model and they shouldn't have the direct dependency or tight coupling.

Remember its a wise thing to adjust anything that fits with your own needs, either by working with `AutoMapper` [custom value resolvers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) and [type converters](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html) to do the proper mapping,
or override the default implementation in-place to whatever you see fit for your scenario and business needs.

**Note:** Please [refer to this document](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/having-the-domain-model-separate-from-the-persistence-model/#:%7E:text=To%20make%20your%20code%20base,out%20of%20the%20domain%20classes.) if you would like to know more details.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The aim is to have the app use a different model to that of my database, but I would usually end up fetching the data from the database then mapping it on every call, I'm just wondering if there is a structure to the code where that would become easier?

Comment: You can use of auto mapper but if that doesn't meet your requirements then you can use your custom way, apart from that there is no concrete way to do that which directly fits to your scenario, based on your business needs you have to consider which match to your needs but you should consider the point I expalined above